# Sorting command line arguments in C

Tags: c

I need to create a program that sorts command line strings. (Example output under code)
This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringcomp (const void * x, const void * y);   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
int i,j;
int k = 1;
char strings[argc-1][20]; 

strcpy(strings[0], argv[1]);
for(i=2; i< argc-1; i++){       
  strcat(strings[k],argv[i]);
  k++;
}
qsort(strings, argc, 20, stringcomp);
for(j=0 ; j < argc-1; j++){  
    printf("%s ", strings[j]);  
}  
return 0;  
}

int stringcomp (const void *x, const void *y) {  
return (*(char*)x -*(char*)y);  
}
```

This is what I type into the command line:
./inOrder hello darkness my old friend

This is what I should get:
darkness friend hello my old

But this is what I keep getting:
?darkness ?old   ]@my

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `strings[k]` is uninitialized and thus cannot use it in `strcat`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin we were required to use the qsort function

Comment: Why write your own `stringcomp()` function when the `strcmp()` library function already does what you want?  Or if you do write your own `stringcomp()` (perhaps because, technically, `strcmp()` does not have the correct parameter types) then why are you not just using that to implement your own comparison?

Comment: Why use a 2D array of `char` for your temp array instead of a 1D array of `char *`?  Not only would the latter help you avoid some initialization pitfalls, it would also remove the current 20-`char` limit on the strings you can sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from the comments, in order to compare the strings and sort an array of strings, you have 2-levels of indirection to deal with. So your `stringcomp` function will need to look something like:

```
int stringcomp (const void *x, const void *y) {  
    return strcmp (*(char * const *)x, *(char * const *)y);  
}
```

Beyond that, instead of copying strings, why not just sort an array of pointers to sort the arguments in correct order? Something like the following is all you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringcomp (const void * x, const void * y);   

int main (int argc, char **argv) {  

    char *strings[argc-1];  /* declare an array of pointers */
    int i;

    /* assign each argument to a pointer */
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        strings[i-1] = argv[i];

    /* sort the array of pointers alphabetically with qsort */
    qsort (strings, argc - 1, sizeof *strings, stringcomp);

    /* output the results */
    for (i = 0; i < argc-1; i++)
        printf("%s ", strings[i]);  

    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;  
}

int stringcomp (const void *x, const void *y) {  
    return strcmp (*(char * const *)x, *(char * const *)y);  
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sort_argv my dog has fleas
dog fleas has my
```

Look it over and let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helps -- there is always more than one way to skin-a-cat in C `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. There is no need to use strcat. Also I removed some of your variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 20 /* maximum string length */

int stringcomp (const void * x, const void * y);   

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  

    int i;
    int argCount = argc-1;
    char strings[argCount][MAX_STRING]; 


    /* copy from argv */
    for (i = 0; i < argCount; i++){
        strcpy( strings[i], argv[i + 1]);
    }

    /* sort the words*/
    qsort (strings, argCount, MAX_STRING, stringcomp);

    /* print the results */
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < argCount; i++){
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    return 0;  
}


int stringcomp (const void *x, const void *y) {  
    return (*(char*)x -*(char*)y);  
}
```

Hope this helps :)